# Items not filtered in RSS feed

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, feed

The RSS feed seems not to have the same filter as the site does. A bogus post with some expletives showed up in the feed but not on the site. Could this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because by the time of the RSS baking and delivering itself to your aggregator of choice, the spam filled and/or hateful sandwich was deleted just a little too late for it to not be captured and push your way.

Might be solved if the feed baking was done a little later. But who knows when the questions are deleted/removed/closed before making it into the feed update?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by random, this is purely a timing issue and thus impossible to reliably control; if you happen to get the feed before the posts are deleted ...